# mysql class instance not recognized

Tags: php, sql, oop

I am trying to figure out what this ancient php sql code does by having it write to a text file instead of editing the sql database.  This `for` loop is giving me major issues though. It just doesn't return anything! I think it has something to do with the curly bracket variable `${$currID}`.

The `$ids` variable is an array of gages pulled from a website which works fine because I can `echo $ids[$i];` and it returns the number of the gage.

Oh yeah, and the parts that are commented out are original parts of code that I've ommited to avoid editing the sql database. I thought it might be important to include them.

```
$file = fopen("test.txt","w");
$intizzler = count($ids);

for($i=0; $i<$intizzler; $i++){
//echo ($i+1) . " / " . $intizzler . ":";
$currID = $ids[$i];
${$currID} = new gage($currID);

//mysql_query("INSERT INTO gage
    //(id,lng,lat,title,text,pic,datum,coords,county)VALUES(
    echo fwrite($file,${$currID}->getField('id'));
    echo fwrite($file,${$currID}->getField('long'));
    echo fwrite($file,${$currID}->getField('lat'));
    echo fwrite($file,${$currID}->getField('title'));
    echo fwrite($file,${$currID}->getField('text'));
    echo fwrite($file,${$currID}->getField('pic'));
    echo fwrite($file,${$currID}->getField('datum'));
    echo fwrite($file,${$currID}->getField('coords'));
    echo fwrite($file,${$currID}->getField('county'));
    //)") or die(mysql_error());

//echo "Write complete for $currID <br/>";
}
```

I'm completely stumped.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And why do you need `${$currID}` if you use it only in a for-loop?

Comment: is $currID must resolve to a valid variable name , i'm guessing it is a string so that's why you are falling down

Comment: @Orangepill talks correctly. But it's not a string, i think,it's a number probably, and php variable name can't start with number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to include a `mysql_query`!  Now I'm able to access the code!

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from mytable");
```

It was so simple!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments when using variable variables the variable still has to resolve to a valid variable name. Try this instead:

```
<?php

$file = fopen("test.txt","w");
$intizzler = count($ids);

for($i=0; $i<$intizzler; $i++){
//echo ($i+1) . " / " . $intizzler . ":";
$currID = $ids[$i];
$gage = new gage($currID);

//mysql_query("INSERT INTO gage
    //(id,lng,lat,title,text,pic,datum,coords,county)VALUES(
    echo fwrite($file,$gage->getField('id'));
    echo fwrite($file,$gage->getField('long'));
    echo fwrite($file,$gage->getField('lat'));
    echo fwrite($file,$gage->getField('title'));
    echo fwrite($file,$gage->getField('text'));
    echo fwrite($file,$gage->getField('pic'));
    echo fwrite($file,$gage->getField('datum'));
    echo fwrite($file,$gage->getField('coords'));
    echo fwrite($file,$gage->getField('county'));
    //)") or die(mysql_error());

//echo "Write complete for $currID <br/>";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried this same thing earlier and it didn't change anything. It was one of the first things I thought of. Thanks though!

Comment: print_r/var_dump the variable you assign `new gage($currID)` to make sure you are getting what you expect there..

Comment: Yeah, its weird, when I do that, nothing happens! and neither `print_r` or `var_dump` work inside the loop with other variables like `$ids`. However, when I use it outside the loop, it works fine.

Comment: echo out $intizzler after you assign it.... you are never entering the loop is my guess

Comment: That variable works too. Is it possible to have issues entering the loop with all the parameters of the loop are working?

Comment: if $intizzler is a integer > 0 you will enter the loop at least once.

Comment: based on your comment should `echo fwrite($file,$gage->getField('long'));` really be `echo fwrite($file,$gage->getField('lng'));` if that is triggering an error and you have error reporting turned off that could account for your behavior

Comment: Sorry, that didn't change anything either but I won't be able to work on this today any longer.  Thanks for all your help!